# Docker build getting stuck

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

[image: screenshot of Terminal output]

I am using Windows,
I have tried things like

1. Docker Restart
2. System Restart

Still, I am getting the same issue of the Image getting stuck while pulling. Thanks for help

Comment: It looks like network connectivity issue. Please try to get more information by running `docker build --progress plain .`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it was not due to a network issue. The corporate protect was blocking the download of some items. Thankfully it resolved!